# What would be the proper naming convention for a Python module, class and instance variable having the same base name?

Tags: python, naming-conventions

First, I am fully aware about [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), but sometimes it isn't very clear about how should you name things.

Let's assume we have `ABC` as an abbreviation.

- **Module** should be named: `abc`
- **Class** inside the module should be named: `Abc` or `ABC`? (not sure)
- **Instance** variable should be named `abc`

```
# abc.py
CONSTANT = "foo"
class Abc(object):
    pass

# test.py
import abc

print abc.CONSTANT
abc_ = abc.Abc() # oops, if I use `abc` will lose ability to access abc.FOO ?
```

If you have a constant inside the `abc` module, you may want to access it using `abc.CONSTANT` from outside but if you also have the instance with the same name it will not be clear?

If there a clean way to solve this kind of problem? Is the solution different if instead of an acronym you just have a simple word?

Note: `Abc()` class acts most of the time as Singleton, so for this reason I wasn't able to find another name for the instance.

Comment: Usually one module is not limited to a single class in Python, so you can avoid naming problems there already. Try to group common class objects in a more general module.

Comment: for Singletons the naming convention [className]Instance is often used. E.g: abcInstance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Module: abc
Class: Abc

Instance: the instance can be named like the class, but it is definitively not required.
In your case, I'd give the variable a name describing the instance to avoid the naming clash!

Example:

```
class Car:
    pass
audi = Car()
myCar = Car()
myBrothersCar = Car()
```

Comment: Instance names should use underscore as delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Class name could be `Abc` or `ABC`, depending if it's an abbreviation or a plain name.

Example with abbreviation: `CRCCheckerTool`.